# MPAndroidChart: add custom image inside bars

Tags: android, graph, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and I want to show a custom drawable inside this `CombinedChart`  like in below image:

[image: a bar chart with star images inside the bars]

If bar value is >= a goal value, say, 50, then I would like to add a star image inside the bar.

Can any one help me for customise the BarChart?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get the star image inside our bars, we will need to create a custom renderer. Because our bar chart uses `BarChartRenderer` we will subclass this first and add a parameter for our image:

```
public class ImageBarChartRenderer extends BarChartRenderer {

    private final Bitmap barImage;

    public ImageBarChartRenderer(BarDataProvider chart, ChartAnimator animator, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler, Bitmap barImage) {
        super(chart, animator, viewPortHandler);
        this.barImage = barImage;
    }
```

If we inspect the source for `BarChartRenderer` we can see that it calls the method called `drawData` and then iterates through each DataSet and calls `drawDataSet`. `drawDataSet` is where the action is happening: it's drawing the shadows and the bars. It's an appropriate place to add logic to draw an extra like images, so let's add a call to a method to draw our images there:

```
    @Override
    protected void drawDataSet(Canvas c, IBarDataSet dataSet, int index) {
        super.drawDataSet(c, dataSet, index);
        drawBarImages(c, dataSet, index);
    }
```

We now need a method that will iterate through the DataSet and draw the star images. An appropriate method that will serve as a template is `drawValues` so let's copy that and change it so that is draws an image rather than text. The key to understanding this is seeing how BarBuffer works. BarBuffer holds the on-screen (pixel) co-ordinates for a bar for a given Entry at `j`, `j + 1`, `j + 2`, `j + 3`.

To clarify, `j` is the left x co-ordinate, `j + 1` is the top y co-ordinate and so on through to the right x co-ordinate at `j + 3`. We'll extract these to variables to make it easier to understand:

```
    protected void drawBarImages(Canvas c, IBarDataSet dataSet, int index) {
        BarBuffer buffer = mBarBuffers[index];

        float left; //avoid allocation inside loop
        float right;
        float top;
        float bottom;

        for (int j = 0; j < buffer.buffer.length * mAnimator.getPhaseX(); j += 4) {
            left = buffer.buffer[j];
            right = buffer.buffer[j + 2];
            top = buffer.buffer[j + 1];
            bottom = buffer.buffer[j + 3];

            float x = (left + right) / 2f;

            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(x))
                break;

            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsY(top)
                    || !mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(x))
                continue;

            BarEntry entry = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(j / 4);
            float val = entry.getY();

            if (val > 50) {
                drawStar(c, barImage, x, top);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's how to consume the renderer:

```
    Bitmap starBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.star);
    mChart.setRenderer(new ImageBarChartRenderer(mChart, mChart.getAnimator(), mChart.getViewPortHandler(), starBitmap));
```

The final step to the renderer is to add logic to scale the bitmap and position it correctly. Here is the final proof-of-concept of the custom renderer:

```
package com.xxmassdeveloper.mpchartexample;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.animation.ChartAnimator;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.buffer.BarBuffer;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.dataprovider.BarDataProvider;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.IBarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.BarChartRenderer;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ViewPortHandler;

/**
 * Created by David on 29/12/2016.
 */

public class ImageBarChartRenderer extends BarChartRenderer {

    private final Bitmap barImage;

    public ImageBarChartRenderer(BarDataProvider chart, ChartAnimator animator, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler, Bitmap barImage) {
        super(chart, animator, viewPortHandler);
        this.barImage = barImage;
    }

    @Override
    public void drawData(Canvas c) {
        super.drawData(c);
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawDataSet(Canvas c, IBarDataSet dataSet, int index) {
        super.drawDataSet(c, dataSet, index);
        drawBarImages(c, dataSet, index);
    }

    protected void drawBarImages(Canvas c, IBarDataSet dataSet, int index) {
        BarBuffer buffer = mBarBuffers[index];

        float left; //avoid allocation inside loop
        float right;
        float top;
        float bottom;

        final Bitmap scaledBarImage = scaleBarImage(buffer);

        int starWidth = scaledBarImage.getWidth();
        int starOffset = starWidth / 2;

        for (int j = 0; j < buffer.buffer.length * mAnimator.getPhaseX(); j += 4) {
            left = buffer.buffer[j];
            right = buffer.buffer[j + 2];
            top = buffer.buffer[j + 1];
            bottom = buffer.buffer[j + 3];

            float x = (left + right) / 2f;

            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(x))
                break;

            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsY(top)
                    || !mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(x))
                continue;

            BarEntry entry = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(j / 4);
            float val = entry.getY();

            if (val > 50) {
                drawImage(c, scaledBarImage, x - starOffset, top);
            }
        }
    }

    private Bitmap scaleBarImage(BarBuffer buffer) {
        float firstLeft = buffer.buffer[0];
        float firstRight = buffer.buffer[2];
        int firstWidth = (int) Math.ceil(firstRight - firstLeft);
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(barImage, firstWidth, firstWidth, false);
    }

    protected void drawImage(Canvas c, Bitmap image, float x, float y) {
        if (image != null) {
            c.drawBitmap(image, x, y, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a screen shot - you can see that values over 50 have the star:

[image: bar chart with custom image inside bars]

Comment: What version of mpandroid chart did you use here ?

Comment: @Amalo version 3.0.1

Comment: This question for more information about writing a custom renderer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43443787/5241933

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (i in 0 until values.size) {
        if (values[i].y.toInt() >= 8000) {
            values[i].icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.oval_check)
        }
    }
```

Comment: "values" type is ArrayList<BarEntry>()

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a custom renderer, you can just use the iconsOffset property on BarDataSet

```
barDataSet.iconsOffset = MPPointF.getInstance(CHART_ICON_X_OFFSET, CHART_ICON_Y_OFFSET)
```