# Bar chart optimization for large range

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using the [MPAndroid](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library to create bar charts.
To create a barEntry, we make an object like (2, 10) which represents the (x, y) values.

I wanted to know if it's possible to create entries such as this (2-10, 10)
where 2-10 is the range.

I know this can be achieved by looping through the range and creating the bar entries individually. Also, reducing the space between the bars will make them appear as a single bar. But this method becomes very costly once the range increases.

Is there some other optimized approach to achieve this ?

Comment: Apart from the approach you mentioned (creating entries individually and reducing space to make appear as a single bar) the only other way would be to create a custom BarChartRenderer. You would do that by inspecting the source code for the same and adapting it to your needs. There is an example of a custom renderer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41340819/mpandroidchart-add-custom-image-inside-bars)

Comment: thanks for answering. For now, I am using a line chart. Coloring the area under the line makes it look like a bar which gets the job done. This won't work for every scenario but it will do for my particular case.